# Convert a list of str and lists to dict

Tags: python

In Python, how do I convert a list that contains strings and lists that have two values into a dictionary such that the key is the string and the value is a list of lists such that the first value of each list is the key.

For example, the current list I have is:

```
['A', ['A', 1], 'B', ['B',1], ['B',2], 'C', ['C', 1], ['C',2], ['C',3]]
```

and I want the dictionary:

`{'A': [['A', 1]], 'B': [['B',1], ['B',2]], 'C': [['C',1], ['C',2],` ['C',3]]}

Thank you.

EDIT: The number of lists that follow a string is arbitrary.

Comment: I tried to create a dictionary with just keys and initial value 0 but I can't think of efficient way to populate the dictionary into what I want.

Comment: Please share the code so that we can help you better

Comment: Currently trying the code of the answers below, but getting errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this, no matter the order of the list, it selects exactly what you're looking for.

```
def new(list_):
    new_dic = {x:[y for y in list_ if type(y) == list and y[0] == x] for x in list_ if type(x) == str}
    print(new_dic)

new(['A', ['A', 1], ['A',2], 'B', ['B',1], ['B',2], 'C', ['C', 1], ['C',2]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {l: [] for l in mylist if type(l) is str} 

for l in mylist:
    if type(l) is list:
        d[l[0]].append(l)
```

Comment: The values are empty list because you didn't evaluate if the first value of the lists match the key.

Comment: Actually you will get `KeyError` if first value of list does not match a key in the dictionary... you can catch this exception if it is not known if all lists will be added.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict
my_dict = defaultdict(list)
my_list = ['A', ['A', 1], ['A',2], 'B', ['B',1], ['B',2], 'C', ['C', 1], ['C',2]]
for index in my_list:
    if len(index) > 1:
        my_dict[index[0]].append(index)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it doesn't matter what the string values are in your list. Based on the current structure of the list provided, and the required output, you can just check for the *lists* inside the list, and by using the [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) construct, you can simply just craft your dictionary accordingly:

```
from collections import defaultdict

l = ['A', ['A', 1], 'B', ['B',1], ['B',2], 'C', ['C', 1], ['C',2], ['C',3]]

d = defaultdict(list)
for data in l:
    if type(data) is list:
        d[data[0]].append(data)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'A': [['A', 1]], 'C': [['C', 1], ['C', 2], ['C', 3]], 'B': [['B', 1], ['B', 2]]})
```

So, here, the `defaultdict` will take a list as its default collection value. Therefore, when adding a new key, the default value will be a list. As you iterate over the list, simply check the type of the data in the list. When you find a `list`, you insert it in to your dictionary taking the first value of that list as the key, and then append the list as the value. It should give you the output you are looking for.

Comment: I am getting TypeError: first argument must be callable or None

Comment: @Mat.S I copy pasted the code in my answer and it runs fine. What input are you providing?

Comment: @Mat.S note that list in defaultdict(list) is the standard type 'list' and not an already initialized list.

Comment: Yes, @Mat.S do not pass *your* list in to defaultdict. The `list` I am passing in `defaultdict` is the standard type *list* to declare to the `defaultdict` that the default value in the dictionary to be used is a list. If you look at my solution, it is complete. It works as is with the input you provided in your question. Look at it carefully, you will see how it works.

Comment: Typing d = defaultdict(list) gives me the error for some reason.

Comment: @Mat.S you are most likely probably using list as a name for your own list in your code which you should not be doing. Make sure that you are variable name that is holding your data is not actually list. That is what is most likely happening

Comment: @idjaw I didn't define any of my variables to be called list.

Comment: @Mat.S thats very odd. You seem to have found an answer that works for you, but the error you get with this code indicates that something seems to be interfering with the expected behavour. The error message was replicated on my end by replicating what was suspected to be happening on your end.

Comment: Needed __builtins__.list instead of list for some reason.